# How do I defeat Golem?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I tried to cage Golem but it wouldn't work, because of the lasers it shoots. How do I evade/defend against the lasers? I am in the latest version of mobile. I've seen videos. In the videos the lasers disappear when it hits a block. For me, the lasers go through the block. What is an easier way of fighting it? What's an easier way to defeat it???

Answer (score 1):

Build a shortish minecart track fairly high above the spawner. If you ride it durning the fight you will dodge most projectiles. Don't make it too wide or high that you can't damage him. I recommend the nimbus rod, it provides constant damage and healing if you wear specter armour with the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making an arena with minimal obstructions:

1. Remove the traps in the boss room
2. Place 3-4 rows of platforms across the length of the room
3. Make sure you place at least one campfire, honey pool and/or heart lantern for health regeneration
4. You must have appropriate Post-Plantera gear like the Hallowed armor with the respective helmet for your class
5. Get at least one of the following potions:

   - Ironskin
   - Regeneration
   - Swiftness

The Golem has been patched many times to prevent glitches and easy routes, so I suggest you do it the way it's meant to be done. Good luck!

Comment: I mean there is no way it's "meant to be done" considering the variety of weapon and armour types, not to mention equipment, there are many many different ways for it to be done. So what do you mean by "the way it's meant to be done."?

Comment: This tells OP how to construct an arena and prepare for the fight, but nothing about how to actually defeat the boss. Do they have certain patterns or attacks to watch out for? Is there an insta-kill laserbeam two thirds of the way through? We can't assume they know these things, and it would be nice to tell them in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, by "the way it's meant to be done." I meant without glitches or loopholes, because many of them have been patched including the wall trapping glitch I used to use. As for tactics, I can only speak on normal mode where I am familiar with its attack patterns. In the beginning of the fight the Golem will throw punches as well as fireballs at you which are both easy to dodge provided you stay at an elevated height and have some sort of dash ability (tabi), or even regular wings. You will notice that as you deal damage the Golem's attacks will become more frequent an